# Use threading to spawn multiple processes to fetch the data in python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I novice to threads in python. Trying to implement it first time. I want to use threading to spawn multiple processes. I have 
written code below where I am trying to fetch data from the spark sql query. When I am trying to pull data without threading, this
query is taking lot of time as it has to scan 70 gb of data. So, I want to do it through threadding to get the better performance.
I have written code below I am not sure, it is right or not.

```
from pyspark import sql, SparkConf, SparkContext,SQLContext
import threading

#conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]').setAppName('appname')
#conf.set('spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts',True)

def task(sc, i):
    dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")\
                                .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://path.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbname")\
                                .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")\
                                .option("dbtable", "test")\
                                .option("user", "user")\
                                .option("password", "pwd")\
                                .load()
    dataframe_mysql.registerTempTable("data")
    data_2015_00=sqlContext.sql("select * from data where date='2015-01-15 00:00:00' LIMIT 1000")
    print(sc.parallelize(data_2015_00).show())

def run_multiple_jobs():
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]').setAppName('appname')
  # Set scheduler to FAIR: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application
    conf.set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')
    conf.set('spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts', True)
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

    for i in range(4):
        t = threading.Thread(target=task, args=(sc, i))
        t.start()


run_multiple_jobs()
```

This code is not working fine. And I am getting the below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o249.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\vk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Users\vk\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-6-8ec48a6ee660>", line 8, in task
    print(sc.parallelize(data_2015_00).show())
  File "D:\Users\vk\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 470, in parallelize
    os.unlink(tempFile.name)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\Users\\vk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\spark-7741cdcd-f85d-4f9c-8a41-50bf6f293dbc\\pyspark-fb73a703-e797-44c7-b56a-0e08999aea3a\\tmp4w72p_jj'
```

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks